# Pandas - create new columns with groupby sum and where clause

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I was using the following line of code to set a groupby sum to a new column

```
df['new_col'] = df.groupby(['col1', 'col2'])['amount'].transform(sum)
```

This worked pretty well, but I also need to only sum amounts for where another col(map) is a certain value

I tried using this:

```
df['new_col'] = df[df['map'] == 'newCol'].groupby(['col1', 'col2'])['amount'].transform(sum)
```

But got an error: "ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis"

**I cannot use boolean indexing right before the first example because  I need to create several new columns, each with map as a new value. Therefore, I can't keep modifying the df in place like that.**

EDIT:

Data sample:

```
d={'source': {'0': 'r', '1': 'r', '2': 'r', '3': 'r', '4': 'r'}, 'date': {'0': Timestamp, '1': Timestamp, '2': Timestamp, '3': Timestamp, '4': Timestamp}, 'name': {'0': 'A', '1': 'A', '2': 'A', '3': 'A', '4': 'A'}, 'codename': {'0': 'D', '1': 'D', '2': 'D', '3': 'E', '4': 'F'}, 'map': {'0': 'X', '1': 'X', '2': 'X', '3': 'X', '4': 'Y'}, 'amount': {'0': 250.0, '1': 450.0, '2': 360.0, '3': 10.0, '4': -436.0}, 'extra': {'0': 'P', '1': 'P', '2': 'P', '3': 'P', '4': 'P'}}

df = pd.DataFrame(d)
```

Grouping by date, name, and extra. All the new columns are going to be summing by amount where map equals a different value.

Comment: Can you post a sample of your data? `df.head().to_dict()` helps

Comment: The data is private, so I can't

Comment: I don't think it'll help, but I added it

Comment: Just ran `df[df.map == "X"].groupby(['date', 'name', 'extra'])['amount'].transform(sum)` with the provided data and it works. I can't reproduce your problem

Comment: That doesn't raise an error for me either with the full data. It's setting it to a new column (like 'X_Sum') that throws the error

Comment: Figured it out anyway. See below

Comment: I'm glad you solved it :)

Comment: I was wrong, there's actually still a small issue remaining

Answer (score 1):

[Didn't actually solve it, small caveat]

Ok figured it out

```
df['new_col'] = df['amount']
df = df[df['map'] == 'X'].groupby(['col1', 'col2'])['new_col'].sum().reset_index()
```

Edit: This answer actually has a small issue. It comes up when trying to make more than one new column

```
df['new_col'] = df['amount']
df['new_col2'] = df['amount']
df = df[df['map'] == 'X'].groupby(['col1', 'col2'])['new_col'].sum().reset_index()
df = df[df['map'] == 'Y'].groupby(['col1', 'col2'])['new_col2'].sum().reset_index()
```

Since the first groupby excludes the map and new_col2 columns, the second one obviously won't work (KeyError)